# I got an error in the joomla installation process

Tags: mysql, joomla

Error

Table 'joomla_db.#__usergroups' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT INTO `#__usergroups` (`id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `title`) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 18, 'Public'), (2, 1, 8, 15, 'Registered'), (3, 2, 9, 14, 'Author'), (4, 3, 10, 13, 'Editor'), (5, 4, 11, 12, 'Publisher'), (6, 1, 4, 7, 'Manager'), (7, 6, 5, 6, 'Administrator'), (8, 1, 16, 17, 'Super Users'), (9, 1, 2, 3, 'Guest')

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci' at line 11 SQL=CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__usergroups` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key', `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Adjacency List Reference Id', `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Nested set lft.', `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Nested set rgt.', `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `idx_usergroup_parent_title_lookup` (`parent_id`,`title`), KEY `idx_usergroup_title_lookup` (`title`), KEY `idx_usergroup_adjacency_lookup` (`parent_id`), KEY `idx_usergroup_nested_set_lookup` (`lft`,`rgt`) USING BTREE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error mainly occur because of old version of MySQL just upgrade MySQL version and problem solved
As a workaround replace (`lft`,`rgt`) USING BTREE with USING BTREE (`lft`,`rgt`).

But you should upgrade MySQL!